# How to prove that $\det \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & A\\ -B & I \end{array}\right) = \det(AB) $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Show that
$$\det
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & A\\
-B & I
\end{array}\right) = \det(AB)
$$ 
where A, B are compatible matrices, 0 and I are zero and identity matrices of the appropriate size.

I don't know where to start for this proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Try multiplying by a block matrix (whose determinant will turn out to be $1$) to turn this into block diagonal form $$\begin{pmatrix} AB & 0 \\ -B & I\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It really helps!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have follow-up questions, let me know. Otherwise, when you get it figured out, you can accept the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\det \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} = \det\left[D\right] \det\left[A - BD^{-1} C \right]$$

Also,

$$\det[I]=1.$$

Now simply do the pattern matching.